# Sanity GROQ query: return pages in the order of items in the array

Tags: sanity, groq

I am looking to return certain pages where there ID is in an array of page ID's, using the following GROQ query:

```
*[_type == "page" && _id in ["ea62b903-cbf9-4c47-90b4-a893aecf276e","77eeb0e8-0368-420b-abfa-a8773d064a8c","cb81057d-db1e-4127-bc97-5e3b81aead7d","90bfad56-6396-471e-9db8-2a45f3ff6a79"]]
```

However, the pages returned in the result are not in the order of page ID's in my array...i.e. the page with the ID 'ea62b903-cbf9-4c47-90b4-a893aecf276e' is not returned first. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dedicated number-type field on each page and then use that field for GROQ ordering. That way you can set up each page's place in the order, something like:

```
*[_type == "page"] | order(sorting_number asc)
```

I'm using something like that when I need to allow clients to create and place navigation menu items.

If you have simple pages you can even use a schema "Pages" that has an array of actual pages. That way you can sort pages by dragging them in place with the mouse in Studio, creating the order those pages will be queried.

Comment: Thanks. My schema is set up in that way actually, where the pages can be dragged into place. I'm then creating an array of '_ref's' of each of those pages to use in my GROQ query. So they're in the correct order in the query, but they're not returned in the correct order in the result.

Comment: I'm using the same thing but for ads columns, where my client can add/remove/sort the ads on the side of the post. All ads are defined as an array item, and I'm just pulling that array with GROQ (in 11ty) and always getting it in the order in which it appears in Sanity Studio.